"React Query useMutation Error: __privateGet(...).defaultMutationOptions is not a function - How to Fix?"
I’m working on a React project using the latest versions of React Query (@tanstack/react-query) and Vite for development. While implementing a useMutation hook for user registration, I ran into the following error:
Unexpected Application Error!
__privateGet(...).defaultMutationOptions is not a function
TypeError: __privateGet(...).defaultMutationOptions is not a function
    at _a11.setOptions (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/@tanstack_react-query.js?v=bed8f3cb:2579:49)
    at new _a11 (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/@tanstack_react-query.js?v=bed8f3cb:2568:10)
    at ...


Below is my code.
`
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { registerUser } from "../apis/Authentication";
import { useMutation } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Register = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const mutation = useMutation(registerUser, {
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      console.log("User registered:", data);
      alert("Registration Successful!");
      navigate("/login-user");
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      console.error("Registration failed:", error);
      alert(error.response?.data?.message || "Registration failed");
    },
  });

  const onSubmit = (formData) => mutation.mutate(formData);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input {...register("username")} placeholder="Username" />
      {errors.username && <p>{errors.username.message}</p>}
      <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Register;


//AxiosInstance File:
import axios from "axios";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/api",
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
});

export default axiosInstance;


import axiosInstance from "../axiosInstance.js";

const registerUser = async (userData) => {
  const response = await axiosInstance.post("/user/register-user", userData);
  return response.data;
};

export { registerUser };


1.Reinstalled Dependencies:
Deleted node_modules and package-lock.json and re-ran npm install.
2.Checked React Query Version Compatibility:
Tried downgrading to older React Query versions (like v4.x), but the issue persists.
3.Node.js Update:
Verified that I am running the latest LTS version using nvm install --lts.
